# How do I write a SQL Concat in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, concatenation

What is the best approach to take to write a concat in Linq? I know that the official word is that you can't but I've heard that there are ways you can accomplish it and I need help to do this. I have a SQL Statement that reads as follows:

```
CONCAT(
   [event_organiser] ,
   ' ', DATEPART(dd,[event_start]),
   '/', DATEPART(mm, [event_start])) 
   AS organiser_info
```

I need to create this in Linq but I'm not sure how to based on my current setup.  Here is my current select statement.

```
var datacontext = db.tbl_events.AsQueryable();

IQueryable<EventsViewModel> theevent = (

             from v in datacontext
             where v.event_start == null
             select new EventsViewModel
             {
                 event_idx = v.event_idx,
                 event_name = v.event_name
                 ...concat goes here..
             });
```

Comment: What is db.tbl_events there? Not a datatable but what? If you don't really need an IQueryable, the easiest would be to use AsEnumerable() and continue with plain C# concat (likely string.Format).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the feedback on this question your comments and examples led me to the answer based on what you have shown me.  Here is what worked for my particular scenario

```
next_charterer_info = string.Concat(p.fixture_charterer ?? "", " ", p.fixture_start.Value.Day, "/", p.fixture_start.Value.Month),
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Just use "+" to join the strings?

```
from v in datacontext
where v.event_start == null
select new EventsViewModel
    {
        event_idx = v.event_idx,
        event_name = v.event_name
        organiser_info = event_organiser + ' ' + ...
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use SqlFunctions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.datepart(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 IQueryable<EventsViewModel> theevent = (

         from v in datacontext
         where v.event_start == null
         select new EventsViewModel
         {
             event_idx = v.event_idx,
             event_name = v.event_name
             organiser_info = v.event_organiser + ' ' + DatePart("dd", v.event_start)
         });
```

Other option is to include all needed columns and extend your `EventsViewModel` with a getter property:

```
public class EventsViewModel
{
    ...
    public string organiser_info 
    {
        get
        {
            return string.format("{0} {1} / {2}", 
                event_organiser,
                event_start.ToString("dd"),
                event_end.ToString("MM"))
        }
    }
}
```

Using this approach you will not be confronted with any non-translatable code constructs in Linq to Entities

Comment: +1. The second method (using a calculated property) will also mean less data transferred from the DB, which has to be a good thing.

Comment: (assuming, that is, that you'd be pulling back those other columns anyway)

Answer (score 1):

```
var theevent = (

         from v in datacontext
         where v.event_start == null
         select new EventsViewModel
         {
             event_idx = v.event_idx,
             event_name = v.event_name
             organiser_info = string.Format("{0} {1}/{2}", event_organiser ?? "", event_start.Date.ToString("d"), event_start.Date.ToString("M"))
         });
```

**UPDATE**

String.Concat(string, string, string) is significantly faster than String.Format(). Also you can write that like this:

```
organiser_info = string.Concat(event_organiser ?? ""," ", event_start.Date.ToString("d"), event_start.Date.ToString("M"))
```

**UPDATE2**

Solution for retrive `IQueryable` odject:

```
IQueryable<EventsViewModel> theevent = (

             from v in datacontext
             where v.event_start == null
             select new EventsViewModel
             {
                 event_idx = v.event_idx,
                 event_name = v.event_name,
                 organiser_info = v.event_organiser ?? "" + 
                 v.event_organiser ? " " : "" +
                 v.event_end ? SqlFunctions.DatePart("Day", v.event_end) : "" +
                 v.event_end ? SqlFunctions.DatePart("Month", v.event_end) : ""
             }
```

Dont forget add `using  System.Data.Objects.SqlClient` for `SqlFunctions.DatePart`.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.datepart(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This function is translated to a corresponding function in the
>   database. For information about the corresponding SQL Server function,
>   see [DATEPART (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).

Comment: That's not going to translate to SQL very well. I assume from the question that the query will be executed against a database, and so you're limited to constructs that the Linq provider for SQL supports. I don't think string.format falls into that category :-). Just use "+" to join the strings?

Comment: I dont really think that all statement  `select new EventsViewModel...` will be translated into sql

Comment: @LayonezWronskey as soon as the query is materialized using .ToList() for example this will fail: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method. Also on this: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: @PeterBons Yeap you right, see new update. I didnt notice `IQueryable` thing (