# How to check if string exists across comma separated concatenated columns in ef core?

Tags: c#, string, entity-framework-core

So I'm trying to see if a string exists across multiple concatenated columns separated by a comma:

For example, my table has columns `address`, `city`, `state` like this:

| Address | City | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 St. | Farmtown | MN |
| 456 Road | Austin | TX |
| 789 Way | Emerald | RH |

So the comma separated concatenated strings would look like this:

```
123 St., Farmtown, MN
456 Road, Austin, TX
789 Way, Emerald, RH
```

Notice the space after each comma

### What I want

Using LINQ method syntax, to be able to input a string like 'St., Farm' and get the 1st row

### What I've tried

```
    var inputString = "St., Farm"

    Expression<Func<MyTable, bool>> validAddressInput =
    x => string.Concat(x.Address, ", ", x.City, ", ", x.StateProvince)
    .Contains(inputString);

    var results = _context.MyTable.Where(validAddressInput).ToList()

    // results should contain that 1st row
```

### Results

> InvalidOperationException - The LINQ expression ' ... ' could not be
> translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> 'AsEnumerable' 'AsAsyncEnumerable' 'ToList' or 'ToListAsync'.

It's clear that it doesn't seem able to translate that `string.Concat(...)` into raw SQL, but I'm not sure what to change it to.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write a SQL Concat in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564011/how-do-i-write-a-sql-concat-in-linq)

Comment: @demo Well, close but not quite. That question uses query syntax and I'm using method syntax.

Comment: @LCIII but issue is the same... SQL server don't know what is `string.Concat` so you need to use something more simple. And in that topic were described other approaches

Comment: Does `string.Join` work? Something like `string.Join(", ", new[] { x.Address, x.City, x.StateProvince });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while `string.Concat` and interpolation `$"{...}"` didn't work, simply using `+` between the strings worked:

```
    Expression<Func<MyTable, bool>> validAddressInput =
    x => (x.Address + ", " + x.City + ", " + x.StateProvince)
    .Contains(inputString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        public async Task<List<MyTable>> Search(string inputString)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyTable), "table");
        var expression = GetExpression(param, nameof(MyTable.State), nameof(MyTable.Address), nameof(MyTable.City), inputString);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyTable, bool>>(expression, param);

        return await _context.MyTable.Where(lambda).ToListAsync();
    }

        private static readonly MethodInfo ContainsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Contains), new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    private static readonly MethodInfo ConcatMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Concat), new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string) });


    private static Expression GetExpression(ParameterExpression param, string propertyName1, string propertyName2, string propertyName3, string searchText) =>
         Expression.Call(Expression.Call(ConcatMethod, Expression.Property(param, propertyName1), Expression.Property(param, propertyName2), Expression.Property(param, propertyName3)),
                    ContainsMethod, Expression.Constant(searchText));
```